# how to write ostream contents to ofstream with open file

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an ostream os that I have been adding text to like so:

```
os << "Hello there" << endl;
```

...and I want to send the text of os to an ofstream ofs with an open file. When I do it like this I seem to get the address of os and not the contents:

```
ofs << os;
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: `ostream` is the base class providing the high-level **output** interface. (That is why it is called **o**stream). If you want to **read** from an `ostream` object, [you're doing something wrong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Answer (score 2):

It is an output stream, not an input stream, so it's not really intended for reading its contents. You may look for `stringstream` instead.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "Hello there" << endl;
ofs << ss.str();
```

Comment: I'd use std::ostringstream here. It's OK to use an output stream since only the whole string is being read.